# HTML shows different DOCTYPE when opening with VIM

Tags: html, vim

I have an HTML file with HTML 5 DOCTYPE. When I open it with TextEdit or any other Mac tools, it shows correctly with HTML 5. However, when I open it using VIM through Terminal, the HTML file shows up completely different, with HTML 4 DOCTYPE.

Original HTML 5 code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="test" lang="bg">
 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" name="viewport">
```

Weird code when opening with VIM:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
  <meta name="CocoaVersion" content="2113.4">
  <style type="text/css">
    p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 12.0px Menlo; color: #440003; -webkit-text-stroke: #440003; background-color: #ffffff}
    p.p2 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 12.0px Menlo; color: #440003; -webkit-text-stroke: #440003}
    span.s1 {font-kerning: none}
    span.Apple-tab-span {white-space:pre}
  </style>
</head>
```

I can hardly believe they are the same file what here they are. What is the reason that made this change happen and what should I do to keep it as the original code everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines you see added are from using TextEdit as an editor for html files, with a brief google search you can find information about it.

Comment: I did some search and I think you are right. My files were destroyed by TextEdit :(

Comment: Here is a more realistic take: you destroyed your files by opening them with TextEdit.

Comment: Downlaod that intellij pack and nothing is getting destroyed :)